# how to get a correlation matrix without any missing values in R?

Tags: r

I need to create a function which takes df which is a data frame and panda which is a string. how to create a function that does the following:

If panda is equal to "col" , the function will return a correlation matrix of all the observations recorded with the variables that don't have missing values.

If panda is equal to "row", the function will return a matrix with all the variables but only with the observations without any missing values.

Comment: Hello Saba Al shawa, can you post a data example (`dput(head(df))`) and of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. Its usually best practice to add some data, the code you have tried, and your expected output. I did, however, think that panda was an interesting choice for variable name, so I thought I'd help you out:

```r
#sample data
dat <- mtcars[1:10, 1:5]
dat[c(1,5), c(2,4)] <- NA
dat
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat
#> Mazda RX4         21.0  NA 160.0  NA 3.90
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7  NA 360.0  NA 3.15
#> Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76
#> Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21
#> Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69
#> Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92
#> Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92

my_fun <- function(df, panda){
  if(!panda %in% c("col", "row")) stop("Invalid input to panda")
  
  if(panda == "col"){
    cor(df[, colSums(is.na(df)) == 0])
  }
  else if(panda == "row"){
    as.matrix(dat[complete.cases(df),])
  }
}

my_fun(df = dat, panda = "col")
#>             mpg       disp       drat
#> mpg   1.0000000 -0.7739868  0.5413585
#> disp -0.7739868  1.0000000 -0.7291389
#> drat  0.5413585 -0.7291389  1.0000000

my_fun(df = dat, panda = "row")
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76
#> Duster 360     14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92

my_fun(df = dat, panda = "anything")
#> Error in my_fun(df = dat, panda = "anything"): Invalid input to panda
```